# hide/show gridview on tabclick

Tags: javascript, c#

I have two GridViews and there are several tabs.  On tab `click`, one grid is to be hidden, the other grid is to be shown.

I have tried making the second grid `visible=false` -- but still the grid is not hidden.

```
protected void RadTabStripClasses_TabClick(object sender, RadTabStripEventArgs e)
{
    RGridMappedDocument.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = string.Empty;
    RGridMappedDocumentSecond.Visible = false;
    RGridMappedDocument.Visible = true;
    string tabId = e.Tab.PageViewID;
    RadPageView pageView = (RadPageView)RadMultiPageClasses.FindPageViewByID(tabId);
    pageView.Controls.Add(RGridMappedDocument);                            
    if(hiddenHeight.Value != "undefined" && hiddenHeight.Value != "NaN" && hiddenHeight.Value != string.Empty)
    {
        RGridMappedDocument.ClientSettings.Scrolling.ScrollHeight = Unit.Pixel(Convert.ToInt16(hiddenHeight.Value));
    }
    RGridMappedDocument.Rebind();
 }
```

Comment: Please, add some code.

Comment: Do `code.Visible=true` on your post first :)

Comment: make sure that you have set `AutoPostBack` property to `true` of TabStrip. And please add aspx markup for TabStrip

Comment: set autopostback=true;..but not getting grid hidden... on tab1 click the first grid is shown but on clicking tab2 the same grid is shown and not the second grid.  When going back to tab1..the two grids are being displayed.

Comment: hi..got corrected..after ajaxification